# Identify specific class when multiple classes of same name

Tags: java, spring

I have two projects included into my `genxml` project, `framework1` and `framework2`. `Framework2` is an updated version of `framework1` and they both have the class `AbstractScreenTest.class`. Is there anyway in the code below I can specify which 
project I want to interact with?

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(AbstractScreenTest.class));
Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents(candiatePackage);

for (BeanDefinition component : components){
  cls = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());
  classList.add(cls.getName().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the @Deprecated annotation to your old (out-dated) class and verify that the component does not contain the deprecated annotation.

```java
for (BeanDefinition component : components){

   cls = Class.forName(component.getBeanClassName());

   if (!cls.isAnnotationPresent(Deprecated.class) {
      classList.add(cls.getName().toString());
   }
}
```

Of course, this assumes that there aren't any other deprecated classes that you want to add to your class list. In that case, you could write a new annotation to stamp your old class with, although it really would be ideal to just get rid of the dependency on an outdated class.

Comment: What can I do if there are multiple versions (2+) of the framework? They are all in use (none are deprecated).

Comment: Do you own the framework? Just because they are in use doesn't mean they can't be deprecated. Unless you have consumers that are on older versions of Java, I don't see why there would be a need to support an out-dated class.

If you don't own the framework and can't stamp it with annotations, all I can think to do is to make the findCandidateComponents class ignore the particular component.

Comment: I don't own the framework but I can make minor adjustments to it. The problem is different people will be working on the different versions of the framework which will eventually merge together. I need to support all the versions of the framework being used

Comment: If all consumers will eventually be on the same version of the framework, my recommendation is to use the @Deprecated annotation. If you're actively supporting the old version you could define a simple annotation, something like \@IgnoreForWhateverPurpose, and stamp it on the class. That's the best advice I can give based on my knowledge of reflection in Java.

Comment: Thanks you've been a lot of help, I'm looking into annotations now.